# Search value of custom coulmn in Woocommerce Admin Orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I got a help from people here to create a coulmn in the woocommerce>orders table to preview the **description** of the **first product** in the order only. by the code below:

Now how can i make it searchable when i search by the value of the column to show the orders that contain that product description only

**All i need is to make this column values to be searchable as they don't now.**

```
/**
 * Adds 'Description' column header to 'Orders' page immediately after 'Order ID' column.
 *
 * @param string[] $columns
 * @return string[] $new_columns
 */
function sv_wc_cogs_add_order_description_column_header( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;
        if ( 'order_number' === $column_name ) {
            $new_columns['order_description'] = __( 'Description', 'my-textdomain' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'sv_wc_cogs_add_order_description_column_header', 99 );

/**
 * Adds 'Description' column content to 'Orders' page immediately after 'Order ID' column.
 *
 * @param string[] $column name of column being displayed
 */
function sv_wc_cogs_add_order_description_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'order_description' === $column ) {
        $order    = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        if( $order ) {
           $first_line_item_descrp = '';
           foreach ( $order->get_items( 'line_item' ) as $item_id => $item ) {
               $product      = $item->get_product();
               $first_line_item_descrp = $product->get_description();
               break;
           }
           echo $first_line_item_descrp;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'sv_wc_cogs_add_order_description_column_content', 99 );
```

I want now to be able to search by "success event" for example that is in **"event"** column that is generated by the product description of the first item in the order is it possible ?

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: This is order search and order search fetch data from `postmeta` and `woocommerce_order_items`  table but the product description value comes from  `posts` table and field name `post_content`.  You need customization in plugin file but when you update plugin then this file will update.

Comment: Please check this link:- https://www.skyverge.com/blog/searching-custom-fields-woocommerce-order-admin/

Comment: The filter linked to on skyverge is the correct and simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code.

> Note: When the Plugin update this code will automatically remove.

Solution:-
File Path:/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php

Function name :- `search_orders()`

After this code

```
if (is_numeric($term)) {$order_ids[] = absint($term);}
```

Add this code

```
$data_store = WC_Data_Store::load('product');
$product_ids = $data_store->search_products($term, ' ', true, false, '');

$custome_order_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT order_items2.order_id
                            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_itemmeta
                            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items2 ON order_items2.order_item_id = order_itemmeta.order_item_id
                            WHERE order_itemmeta.meta_value IN ('" . implode("','", $product_ids) . "') AND order_itemmeta.meta_key = %s", '_product_id'
            )
        );
$order_ids = array_merge($order_ids, $custome_order_ids);
```

**Note: When Plugin update this code will remove.**

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203578/discussion-between-wp-developer-and-maged-mohamed