# woocommerce thank you message based on payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the thank you message if a payment method is chosed, i have achieved this and working but still don't aware of the need of this line here in the code below do i need it ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'woo_change_order_received_text', 20, 2 );
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // do i need this line, it works without it do i need it ????????

    if( 'bacs' == $order->get_payment_method() ) {
    $new_str = $str . '<br><br><span style="display:block;font-weight:bold; text-align:center"> Please after your payment is done make sure to visit </span><br>';
    return $new_str;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

**do i need this line, it works without it do i need it ?**

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that line. The parameters of the hook `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text` are `thank you message string` and `$order` object.

What this line `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`
does is to get the order object `$order` from the order id which is completely unnecessary as you have order object already available inside the function as parameter.

Also note that here in your function, there is no $order_id available in hook parameter. So that line of code has no relevance.

So you can just remove the line.

Comment: @MagedMohamed Happy to help :)

Comment: its my pleasure, can you help in this too we have reached that i can't make it searchable but can we make it sortable in ascending order or filtered using a drop-down ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58499716/search-value-of-custom-coulmn-in-woocommerce-admin-orders-list/59192307#59192307

Comment: the link is answered

Comment: not a correct answer, its a semi correct answer. 
We found that we cannot achieve it completely working as searchable but can we make it sort-able in ascending order or filtered using a drop-down ?